# c# static implicit operator what is its purpose?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I was looking at some code and saw this static implicit operator.  I already read this [MSDN article on static implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) operators but I still dont understand this code.  Can someone please explain what the developer's intentions were.

```
public abstract class Envelope
{
    public static Envelope<T> Create<T>(T body)
    {
        return new Envelope<T>(body);
    }
}

public class Envelope<T> : Envelope
{
    public Envelope(T body)
    {
        this.Body = body;
    }

    public T Body { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator Envelope<T>(T body)
    {
        return Envelope.Create(body);
    }
}
```

Comment: What aspect of the documentation did you have trouble understanding?  The premise is rather straightforward; it creates a user defined implicit conversion from one type to another.  The documentation, and the internet at large, has plenty of examples of its use.

Comment: what is its purpose in this context.. how would they use it here?

Comment: To create an implicit conversion from `T` to `Envelope`.  You'd use it to convert an object to an `Envelope` implicitly.

Comment: So, you can convert any object to an envelope?

Comment: That's what this has defined, yes.

Comment: okay, geeze.. i didn't see that.. the msdn article didnt involve generics..

Comment: If that is what is confusing you then *say so in the question*.  If your question read, something along the lines of, "I understand the basics of an implicit conversion, but I don't understand what happens when an implicit conversion is generic." then your question becomes far more clear, focused, and isn't answered by simply reading the documentation that you say you've read.

Comment: I don't know what I don't know, it was the conversation we had that lead me to the insight.  If I knew what I didn't know then yes, I could have asked a perfect question. Jerk

Comment: he's just trying to help you ask better questions (which in turn will get you better answers both here and in real life). that's why we're here, to learn. no need for name-calling.

Comment: your right, i shouldn't have called him a jerk but i don't like that he downvoted my question and every answer and then marked my question to be closed.  that was not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so you can create implicit conversions from `T` to `Envelope<T>`.

Here's some examples to help you understand:

```
Envelope<string> envelope    = "My string"; // allowed
Envelope<int>    envelopeInt = 1;           // allowed

envelopeInt = 12;                           // allowed
envelopeInt = "string";                     // not allowed (not of type int)

Console.WriteLine(envelope.Body);           // Outputs "My string"
```

Comment: thank you for answering.  Some people are down vote happy

Comment: that servy guy downvoted all the answers after I upvoted.  And he marked the question to be closed.

Comment: I thought the question was straightforward enough; however, it's difficult to tell who downvotes answers so no point in assuming. Downvotes aren't that big of a deal anyways... except one time a guy went through my history downvoting everything after I told him about a bug in his code... again an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

It defines an implicit conversion, and it allows you to do things like

```
Envelope<string> e = "this will be enveloped";
```

Which is the same as

```
Envelope<string> e = new Envelope<string>("this will be enveloped");
```

In both cases, e.Body will be that string.

Comment: @EvanLarsen no problem, this is a perfectly valid question btw. That Servy is kind of rude, but no need to get mad about it :)

Comment: This actually provides the clearest insight to what the code is doing. Under the hood it will call into the Static Create Factory method upon assignment. Pretty neat!